# Is this the best practice for separating all records by user company?

Tags: security, foreign-key, best-practices

This is more of a general database question than specifically a [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) question, but the implementation I have is written using Prisma connected to MySQL.

Take the following part of my `schema.prisma`:

```
model Company {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String  @db.VarChar(255)
  users         User[]
  products      Product[]
  brands        Brand[]
  customers     Customer[]
}

model User {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  first_name    String  @db.VarChar(255)
  last_name     String  @db.VarChar(255)
  email         String  @unique(map: "email") @db.VarChar(255)
  password_hash String? @default("") @db.VarChar(255)
  company       Company @relation(fields:[company_id], references:[id])
  company_id    Int
}

model Product {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String  @db.VarChar(255)
  brand         Brand   @relation(fields:[brand_id], references:[id])
  brand_id      Int
  company       Company @relation(fields:[company_id], references:[id])
  company_id    Int
}

model Brand {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String  @db.VarChar(255)
  products      Product[]
  company       Company @relation(fields:[company_id], references:[id])
  company_id    Int
}

model Customer {
  id            Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title         String  @db.VarChar(50)
  first_name    String  @db.VarChar(255)
  middle_name   String  @db.VarChar(255)
  last_name     String  @db.VarChar(255)
  company       Company @relation(fields:[company_id], references:[id])
  company_id    Int
}
```

As you can see, users, products, brands, and customers are all associated with a company, so as not to allow overlap between companies.

My question is: is there a better, or more concise way to do this? Either in general (as in, a different way of not allowing overlap), or just in the Prisma schema? 'This' referring to relating multiple schemas to the Company one. Especially when adding new products, for example, it's very long winded as I have to connect every subsection (brand, categories etc) to a company and end up repeating myself a bunch.